# PHP extension "curl" must be loaded. PHP extension "gd" must be loaded

Tags: php, apache, magento, wampserver

this is my wamp server details

**apache Version :2.4.4

PHP Version :5.4.12
MySQL Version :5.6.12**

here
am started installing magento-1.7.0.2 in configure page i got

**PHP extension "curl" must be loaded.
PHP extension "gd" must be loaded.**

but in my php.ini

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

are in active only but am getting same issue how to solve this

Comment: Do you remove ; from front of those two lines...?

Comment: check your phpinfo page (<? phpinfo(); ?>). to see if GD is being loaded?

Comment: ya removed ; from those lines @next2u

Comment: done as per u said but i didn't find gd and curl in this page @DushyantJoshi

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't resolve the problem even after uncommenting `extension=php_curl.dll`, Then do the following..

```
1. Click on wamp icon.
2. Navigate to php > php extensions.
3. Enable php_curl in the extension list.
```

Comment: thanks for responding ya done .. still issue not solved is these any way to change the file php_curl.dll and gd2 file??

Answer (score 0):

First create a page and into it, check to see if your extensions are loaded

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```